# iOS - Xcode - Error Starting Executable 'Templatelpone'

Tags: xcode, ios4

Hi all I recieved this error when I tried to run the app on my iPhone.

**Error launching remote program: No such file or directory (/Users/thephone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TemplateIpone-dnfacjtdklqktcazrpfyupofdryp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TemplateIpone.app/TemplateIpone).**

I think I may have messed with the -Info.plist file.

I changed Bundle display name and bundle name, plus added my icon file name.

Anyone else have these issues?

J

PS: The App runs fine on the iPhone if I press the icon manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too edited info.plist and got the same error. A restart of xcode fixed this problem.